# Plugins Jquery usam versões diferentes, como contornar?

Tags: jquery, plugin

Boa tarde estou usando o `pluign` **jQuery Knob** que usa a versão `1.9.0` do jquery, e o **mask-input**  que usa a `v1.11.1`.

> [MaskInput](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Eu usei a versão mais recente e funcionou, então creio que o maskinput não seja o problema.

> [Jquery Knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/)

Só funciona na versão 1.9.0 e se coloco qualquer outra ele não faz nada e nem erro no console aparece.

### O grande Problema

É quando uso o src e mapeio as duas versões do jquery é esse erro que aparece o que devo fazer?

```
Uncaught Error: jquery Knob's JavaScript requires jquery Knob version
1.9.0 or higher, but lower than version 3 at jquery Knob.js:6 
at jquery Knob.js:6
```

Comment: Fiz algumas buscas na internet e tinha alguns tutorias ensinando usar as 2 versões mas não entendi como fazer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566644/6510304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, com o [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) você pode fazer algo assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script> $190 = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

E então usar tanto $190 e $ no seu código. Ex:

```
$('#seletor').function(); ou $190('#seletor').function();
```

Comment: O $190 pega o valor do src anterior a declaração?

Comment: Ele pega o que está no escopo atual do JS. Pra esse caso, utilize antes pare isolar apenas o conteúdo do JS legado.

Comment: Deu certinho @LucasMatias, e eu burra perdendo um bom tempo procurando hahahaha